# Animating a div back and forth

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm not an expert dev. I was looking for a little help.

I was trying to make a div move back and forth using toggleClass;

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

and keyframes;

```
.active {
    animation-name: moveme;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes moveme {
    0%  {transform: translate(0,0)}
    50%  {transform: translate(-200px, 0px)}
    100%  {transform: translate(-200px,-50px);}
}
```

Now, when the div goes back to its previous position, it doesn't animate.
I want the div to animate with the same animation but backwards.
How can I do that?

Here you can see what I'm trying to accomplish [jsfiddle.net/jmrMW/43/](http://jsfiddle.net/jmrMW/43/)
I just made a simple animation for the sake of the example, but it's going to be more complex in the future.

Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript adds and removes classes instantly. And your CSS binds the animation only to `.active` class, so when you click second time - you loose your class - you loose the slight animation.

Now, you can duplicate everything as people mentioned before me, but come on! Programmers never duplicate, they utilize. Isn't it a good idea to discover all the power of CSS3 animations?

So, I'd like to suggest another approach: to set `animation-direction: alternate` and `animation-play-state: paused`. Then define CSS class for moving, either way:

```
.moving {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

And then, apply it to the given element for only 1 sec after it has been clicked:

```
var $moveable = $( '.moveable' ).eq( 0 );

$moveable.click(function() {
    $moveable.addClass( 'moving' );
    setTimeout(function() {
         $moveable.removeClass( 'moving' );
    }, 1000);
});
```

[See fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pttsky/m076fqrp/)

**Update**

This solution has a major downside - using timers in both JS and CSS which obviously won't match. Animation is now infinite, so each time it goes little bit further than should. But we can increment `animation-iteration-count` to disable animation proceeding to the next cycle. Hope that's still fun!

[See fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pttsky/jb2zmc3k/)

Comment: Your timing is a bit off and your animation bounces at either end - seems a bit daft to try to remove the class at exactly the right area of an animation loop rather than having defined actions that have a start and an end - as you can see from your fiddle, timings don't always match up

Comment: @Pete Wow! Indeed, what a bad idea to rely on `setTimeout` sense of time. But still, I won't duplicate my code - [there comes the fix](http://jsfiddle.net/pttsky/djk7z4yw/)

Comment: I knew it required a totally different approach.
Duplicating the animation is fine too, but with complex animations it would require a lot of code to add.
Thank you guys for your solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fork of your JSFiddle. Pretty much just duplicated what you already had for keyframes but applied it in reverse :)

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("go-up") ) {
    $(this).removeClass("go-up").addClass("go-down");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("go-up").removeClass("go-down");
  }
});
```

```css
div{
  background:#aaa;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  height: 200px;
}
.go-up {
  animation-name: moveup;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.go-down {
  animation-name: movedown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes moveup {
  0%  {transform: translate(0,0)}
  50%  {transform: translate(-100px, 0px)}
  100%  {transform: translate(-100px,-50px);}
}

@keyframes movedown {
  0%  {transform: translate(-100px,-50px);}
  50%  {transform: translate(-100px, 0px)}
  100%  {transform: translate(0,0)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmrMW/43/